# How to align title and authors in the left column in ASME document?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I have [this template from ASME website](http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/) for their conference/journal papers:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{asme2e}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\title{Title}

\author{xxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\
{\tensfb xxxxxxxxxxx} \\
{\tensfb xxxxxxxxx\thanks{Address all correspondence to this author.}} 
    \affiliation{
    Lab\\
    Email
    }   
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    
\begin{abstract}
{\it TBD.}
\end{abstract}
\section{INTRODUCTION}

\lipsum[2-4]

\bibliographystyle{asmems4}
\bibliography{asme2e}

\end{document}
```

This generates this document:

[image]

I want however the author, title and abstract to be part of the left column of the first page like this:

[image]

Can someone please point out how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you stick to the template? If this is for a submission, they'll most likely revert your changes back to their original format, don't you think?

Comment: Actually for journal submissions they want left aligned format but they do not provide with such a journal template. All their templates are only for conference papers.

Comment: So I guess you don't have to use the `asme2e` class then, and instead create your own template/document layout?

Comment: Yes that would work. Or if in the `asme2e/asme2ej` style class i could tweak and get my stuff done, that would also be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very elementary template that replicates your requirement:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% Remove tabular column separation
\sffamily
  % Title
{\LARGE\bfseries This is the title}

\hrulefill

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ l }
  \bfseries Random Randofsky \\
  \slshape Institute A \\
  \slshape Country \\
  \slshape email \\[\medskipamount]
  \bfseries Random Randofsky \\
  \slshape Institute B \\
  \slshape Country \\
  \slshape email
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\bigskip

{\itshape \lipsum[1]}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want the title and author details to be left aligned like [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hao_Wang180/publication/276500683_Mobile_Schatz_Mechanism/links/561792e908ae40a7199b8819/Mobile-Schatz-Mechanism.pdf). Could you please show?

Comment: @user_1_1_1: See the updated answer.